# Why does JavaScript force integer variables into string variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a project for school which is a website with many random little projects.
In one of these projects I've embedded a video that has a src link "...blah.../Ndub1" and if you change the "1" from the link to, for example "2", then you get the next video. Now I'm trying to write a javaScript script that will change that number to "number + 1" or to "number - 1" on a button click. Here's the source code of my website:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- some stuff -->
        <script>        
            var e = "1"; 
            var s = "0";
            function narutoGetEpisodeGen() {
                var a, link, link2;
                e = document.getElementById('episodeInput').value
                if (document.getElementById('naruto').checked) {
                    a = "Ndub" + document.getElementById('episodeInput').value;
                    s = 0;
                }
                else {
                    a = "Nshipdub" + document.getElementById('episodeInput').value;
                    s = 1;
                }
                link = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480" width="720">';
                link2 = '<video width="720" height="480" controls><source id="videoEmbeddedVid" src="http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp&autoplay=0" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
                document.getElementById('embeddedVideoDiv').innerHTML = link;
                document.getElementById('videoVidDiv').innerHTML = link2;
                document.getElementById('episodeInput').value = "";
            }

            function oneForward() {
                var a, z, link;
                if (s == 0) {
                    z = eval(parseInt(e)+1);
                    a = "Ndub"+z.toString();
                    e += 1;
                }
                else {
                    z = eval(parseInt(e)+1);
                    a = "Nshipdub"+z.toString();
                    e += 1;
                }           
                link = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480" width="720">';
                link2 = '<video width="720" height="480" controls><source id="videoEmbeddedVid" src="http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp&autoplay=0" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
                document.getElementById('embeddedVideoDiv').innerHTML = link;
                document.getElementById('videoVidDiv').innerHTML = link2;
            }

            function oneBack() {
                var a, x, link;
                if (s == 0) {
                    x = eval(parseInt(e)-1);
                    a = "Ndub"+x.toString();
                    e -= 1;
                }
                else {
                    x = eval(parseInt(e)-1);
                    a = "Nshipdub"+x.toString();
                    e -= 1;
                }
                link = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480" width="720">';
                link2 = '<video width="720" height="480" controls><source id="videoEmbeddedVid" src="http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp&autoplay=0" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
                document.getElementById('embeddedVideoDiv').innerHTML = link;
                document.getElementById('videoVidDiv').innerHTML = link2;
            }
        </script>
        <!-- some stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- some stuff -->
        <p>Number of episode: <input type="text" id="episodeInput"/></p>
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="narutoSeason" id="naruto"> Naruto</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="narutoSeason" id="narutoShippuden"> Naruto Shippuden</label></p>
        <p><button type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="narutoGetEpisodeGen()">Submit</button></p>
        <div id="embeddedVideoDiv">
            <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/Ndub1&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480px" width="720px">
        </div>
        <p><button type="button" onClick="oneBack()">Previous</button>  <button type="button" onClick="oneForward()">Next</button></p>
        <!-- some stuff -->     
    </body>
</html>
```

So the main problem is that the part where I add or substract 1 from the number. First time I use the oneForward button it works normal, but the next time I use that button it just adds "1" to the number of episode I started with. Then the error keeps repeating if I use the same button, but stops occuring if I use the other button and from that point on it works normally.
To make my self extra clear I'll type some examples of what exactly I'm doing.

```
- Type in the input(id="episodeInput"): 3 > click on input(id="narutoShippuden") > click the button(id="submitButton") > observe how the function("narutoGetEpisode") did its job perfectly > click the button(onClick="oneForward") > observe the function working just fine (transformed the number from "3" to "4") > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observer how the link in embedded part transformed the number into "31" > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observer how the link in embedded part transformed the number into "311" > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observer how the link in embedded part transformed the number into "3111" > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observer how the link in embedded part transformed the number into "31111"  > click the button(onClick="oneBack") > observe the function working just fine (transformed the number from "31111" to "31110") > from here on, both buttons act just fine
- Type in the input(id="episodeInput"): 3 > click on input(id="narutoShippuden") > click the button(id="submitButton") > observe how the function("narutoGetEpisode") did its job perfectly > click the button(onClick="oneForward") > observe the function working just fine (transformed the number from "3" to "4") > click the button(onClick="oneBack") > observer how the link in embedded part transformed the number into "30" > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observe how the button did its job okay (transforms the number from "30" to "31") > click the button(onClick="oneForward") again > observe how the button did its job okay (transforms the number from "31" to "32") > click the button(onClick="oneBack") again > observe how the button did its job okay (transforms the number from "32" to "31") > from here on, both buttons act just fine
- Type in the input(id="episodeInput"): 3 > click on input(id="narutoShippuden") > click the button(id="submitButton") > observe how the function("narutoGetEpisode") did its job perfectly > click the button(onClick="oneBack") > observe the function working just fine (transformed the number from "3" to "2") > click the button(onClick="oneBack") > observe the function working just fine (transformed the number from "2" to "1") > from here on, both buttons act just fine
```

I also should mention that this happens in all three, Mozilla, Chrome and IE (all up to date).

So as I was brainstorming through this problem and searching the forums I tried many variants to fix the code, so now I'm going to type the things I tested and worked simmilarly wierd or worse:

To be clear I only cnanged the code in "script" tag in header, more precisely, only in these lines:

```
function oneForward() {
                var a, z, link;
                if (s == 0) {
                    z = eval(parseInt(e)+1);
                    a = "Ndub"+z.toString();
                    e += 1;
                }
                else {
                    z = eval(parseInt(e)+1);
                    a = "Nshipdub"+z.toString();
                    e += 1;
                }           
                link = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480" width="720">';
                link2 = '<video width="720" height="480" controls><source id="videoEmbeddedVid" src="http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp&autoplay=0" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
                document.getElementById('embeddedVideoDiv').innerHTML = link;
                document.getElementById('videoVidDiv').innerHTML = link2;
            }

            function oneBack() {
                var a, x, link;
                if (s == 0) {
                    x = eval(parseInt(e)-1);
                    a = "Ndub"+x.toString();
                    e -= 1;
                }
                else {
                    x = eval(parseInt(e)-1);
                    a = "Nshipdub"+x.toString();
                    e -= 1;
                }
                link = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/player.swf" style="undefined" name="embeddedVid" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="autostart=&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;type=video&amp;skin=http://cdn.directvid.com/jwplayer/nemesis1.zip&amp;file=http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp;plugins=timeslidertooltipplugin-2" height="480" width="720">';
                link2 = '<video width="720" height="480" controls><source id="videoEmbeddedVid" src="http://www.animefun.com/dl/googDev.php?url=/112965806382805543465/' + a + '&amp&autoplay=0" type="video/webm">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
                document.getElementById('embeddedVideoDiv').innerHTML = link;
                document.getElementById('videoVidDiv').innerHTML = link2;
```

so I changed the

```
z = eval(parseInt(e)+1);
a = "Nshipdub"+z.toString();
```

to

```
z = (parseInt(e)+1);
a = "Nshipdub"+z.toString();
```

or

```
z = (e+1);
a = "Nshipdub"+z.toString();
```

or

```
a = "Nshipdub"+(e+1);
```

or

```
a = "Nshipdub"+(e*1+1);
```

or

```
a = "Nshipdub"+(parseInt(e)+1);
```

or

```
a = "Nshipdub"+(parseInt(e)*1+1);
```

or

```
a = "Nshipdub"+(parseInt(e)+1).toString();
```

and some others which I don't even remember any more. Anyway, all of them were no better.

I'd really appreciate some help with this and also an explanation why the above examples wont work, especially the ones with another variable, because I read the examples on forums saying that >"string" + 3+1"< equals to >"string + "3" + "1"< and that the >1+5 + "string"< equals to >6 + "string"<.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why does JavaScript force integer variables into string variables?"

Because, uh...

```
var e = "1";
```

You're defining it as a string?

```
e = document.getElementById('episodeInput').value
```

Twice?

Try:

```
var e = 1;
```

and:

```
e = parseInt(document.getElementById('episodeInput').value,10);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I didn't even think in that direction, but was trying to make it an integer in the x and z variable. It all works now, but just out of curiosity, why wouldnt it work when it was like: x = parseInt(e)+1; ? Also what was that wierd glitch when I used the code above, that the first time i pressed a button it would work (add as integer) and the second it would add as string?